# Using reduction of order to find second solution of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$(x-1)y''-xy'+y=0$

$y_1(x)=e^x$ is a solution of this differential equation, but how can I find a second linearly independent solution?

Here is what I've done so far..

$y_2(x)=ue^x$

$y_2'=u'e^x+ue^x$

$y_2''=u''e^x+u'e^x+u'e^x+ue^x$

Substituting back into the ODE, I get

$(x-1)(u''e^x+u'e^x+u'e^x+ue^x)-x(u'e^x+ue^x)+ue^x=0$

If I simplify this, I get

$x(u''+u'+2u)-u''-2u'=0$ ... Do you get the same?

Now what do I do, if this is correct?

Comment: There should not be any $u$ terms remaining in your final differential equation, go back and check your work (you'll get an equation involving only $u''$ and $u'$ which will be a first order equation in $w = u'$).

Comment: @BaronVT but in the book there are u terms in the final diff eq

Comment: No, there should not be. Once the $u$ term is eliminated, you can let $w=u'$ and reduce it to a first order equation. By the way, can't you just use the formula $y_2=y_1 \int \frac{e^{-\int p dx}}{y_1^2} dx$?

Comment: @JohnTiedam I assure you, there are not. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
(x-1)(u''e^x+u'e^x+u'e^x+ue^x)-x(u'e^x+ue^x)+ue^x \\
= x(u''e^x+u'e^x) - (u''e^x+2u'e^x) + xu'e^x + xue^x- x(u'e^x+ue^x) - ue^x+ ue^x \\
= x(u''e^x+u'e^x) - (u''e^x+2u'e^x)
$$

So solve

$$
(x-1)u'' + (x-2)u' = 0
$$

i.e. solve

$$
(x-1)w' + (x-2)w = 0
$$

for $w$, then $u$ is an antiderivative of $w$ and $y_2 = ue^x$.

Comment: So $y_2=(-e^-x+.5x^2-x+c_1x+c_2)e^x$

Comment: @HansEngler IS this correct?

Comment: I get $y_2 = x$ (which means $u = xe^{-x}$). General solution will be $y = c_1 e^x + c_2 x$.